# Django error : :SyntaxError:Invalidsyntax

Tags: python, django

I am new in django. I learn from youtube django webdevlopment with python. While runserver I found this error:

> File
>   "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\new\personal\urls.py",
>   line 1, in 
>           from . import views
>         File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\new\personal\views.py",
>   line 6
>           `
>           ^

and in new/urls.py

> ```
>      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\new\new\urls.py",
> ```
>
> line 21, in 
>           url(r'^personal/',include('personal.urls')),
>         File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py",
>   line 34, in include
>           urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
>
> File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

my **personal/urls.py** is:

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import *
urlpatterns = [
    url('personal/',views.index,name='index'),
]
```

and **personal/view.py** is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request,'personl/home.html')

# Create your views here.
```

**new/urls.py** is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^personal/',include('personal.urls')),
    url(r'^block/ ',include('block.urls')),
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is inside your block/urls.py? Show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a <kbd>'</kbd> on line 6 of `view.py` Remove that extra character and it should run.

Comment: thx it run but now it show -----> Using the URLconf defined in new.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^personal/
^block/
The current URL, ^block/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: You have an extra space at the end of block/.